# OverflowError in Python sqldf

Tags: python, overflow, sqldf

I use `sqldf` in Python to filter a `DataFrame` with over 100 million data.

I'm getting this error:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include your code so we can give you better help.

Comment: The code
from pandasql import sqldf
x=sqldf("select * from Details")